# MapRoute to specific action in Home controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

Inside my home controller I have two views, `Index` and `About`.

[image]

I'm trying to configure requests to `example.com/about`to hit the `About` page.

Inside my Startup.cs file I have the below MapRoute's

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapRoute(
              "Id",
              "{id}",
              new { controller = "Home", action = "About" });
        });
```

This allow's requests to `example.com/about` to be passed into the `About` action. My problem is that it also captures all other requests after the forwardslash. For instance, requests to `example.com/foobarr`will also hit the `About` action.

How can I alter the MapRoute so that requests to `example.com/about` reach the `About` action, but anything else is ignored.

Comment: Does the `About` action actually take an `Id`?

Comment: No, the About action does not take an id.

Comment: @TidyDev so why are you specifying an `id` in the route template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it better to configure routes inside controllers, specifying attributes above methods, for example:

```
 [HttpGet("Home/About")]
```

The custom attribute is for an action method for about route. In this case it is easier to handle specific routes.

Comment: Thank you, this resolved my issue. I placed `[HttpGet("Home/About")]` in the controller and it's now working as intented.